# How to return two different results in an array in a public function?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am making a Zend framework method for a search engine. Because i search through different tables i also have to make two different select variables and return it. My questions are: Is this a good idea for  a search engine with different tables?

And how to return the different resuls in an array? (`fetchall->$selectMovies`, `fetchall->$selectPosts`)

Thanks and greetz Eric

```
public function search($keyword) {
        $selectPosts = $this->select();
        $selectPosts->from('posts', array('*'));
        $selectPosts->where('posts.post_title LIKE ? OR  posts.post_body LIKE ?', '%'. $keyword . '%' );

        $tblMovies = new Model_DbTable_Film();
        $selectMovies = $tblMovies->select();
        $selectMovies->from('film', array('*'));
        $selectMovies->where('film.titel LIKE ? OR  film.omschrijving LIKE ?', '%'. $keyword . '%' );

        //var_dump($this->fetchAll($selectPosts, $selectMovies)); die;
        return $this->fetchAll($selectMovies);
        return $this->fetchAll($selectPosts); 

    }
```

Comment: Just union the queries into one and leave that to the database.

Comment: You shouldn't mix two table objects' results. Obviously you are searching within an object'S scope that relates to "posts". You add a completely different object related to "movies". These two shouldn't be mixed at this layer. If you want to combine search results of two tables, add another object that does the combining by asking every single table object about search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only return once, but what you can do is return an array of your result arrays.

```
<?php 
public function search($keyword) {
    $selectPosts = $this->select();
    $selectPosts->from('posts', array('*'));
    $selectPosts->where('posts.post_title LIKE ? OR  posts.post_body LIKE ?', '%'. $keyword . '%' );

    $tblMovies = new Model_DbTable_Film();
    $selectMovies = $tblMovies->select();
    $selectMovies->from('film', array('*'));
    $selectMovies->where('film.titel LIKE ? OR  film.omschrijving LIKE ?', '%'. $keyword . '%' );

    //var_dump($this->fetchAll($selectPosts, $selectMovies)); die;

    return array('movies'=>$this->fetchAll($selectMovies),
                 'posts'=>$this->fetchAll($selectPosts));
}
?>
```

Or split up your method into 2 and pass a type of search as a parameter to the main search method:

```
<?php 
public function search($keyword,$type) {
    return $this->{$type}($keyword);
}

public function search_movies($keyword) {
    $tblMovies = new Model_DbTable_Film();
    $selectMovies = $tblMovies->select();
    $selectMovies->from('film', array('*'));
    $selectMovies->where('film.titel LIKE ? OR  film.omschrijving LIKE ?', '%'. $keyword . '%' );
    return $this->fetchAll($selectMovies);
}

public function search_posts($keyword) {
    $selectPosts = $this->select();
    $selectPosts->from('posts', array('*'));
    $selectPosts->where('posts.post_title LIKE ? OR  posts.post_body LIKE ?', '%'. $keyword . '%' );
    return $this->fetchAll($selectPosts);
}
?>

<?php 
$result['movies'] = $model->search($keyword,'search_movies');
$result['posts'] = $model->search($keyword,'search_posts');
?>
```